# VBA Error Handling to check for folder existence

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to implement some 'Error Handling' into an existing script and I've put together the following:

**Edited Code**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Display the splash form non-modally.
Set frm = New frmSplash
With frm
    .TaskDone = False
    .prgStatus.Value = 0
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    .Show False
End With

For j = 1 To 1000
    DoEvents
    Next j

    iRow = 17


    fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\April 2015\"
    If fPath = vbNullString Then GoTo ErrorHandler
    If Not Dir(fPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        frm.prgStatus.Value = 15
        If FSO.FolderExists(fPath) <> False Then
            frm.prgStatus.Value = 30
            Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)
            IsSubFolder = True
            frm.prgStatus.Value = 45
            Call DeleteRows
            frm.prgStatus.Value = 60
                Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
                frm.prgStatus.Value = 75
            Call FormatCells
            frm.prgStatus.Value = 100
            Else
        End If
    End If
    frm.TaskDone = True
    Unload frm
    iMessage = MsgBox("The list has now been been updated!", vbOKOnly)

    '******Error Handling******
    ErrorHandler:
          MsgBox "The filepath does not exist, please contact the       administrator"
    Resume Next
    End Sub
```

In the error handling, I'm trying to check whether the folder exists. If it doesn't, instigate the error message. If it does, run the rest of the script.

The problem is that, even when the file path does exist, the error handler is activated but I'm not sure why despite looking at quite a number of tutorials.

I just wondered whether someone could look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I'm confused; you check for the null path (`If fPath = vbNullString Then GoTo ErrorHandler`) before you assign the variable (`fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\April 2015\"`).  Shouldn't those lines be swapped?  Also, you need an `Exit Sub` before the error handler, otherwise you'll always hit it after updating the list.

Comment: Your `If fPath = vbNullString Then GoTo ErrorHandler` is only checked once at that line. It doesn't continue to check if `fpath` is null throughout the execution of the code that follows it. It`s like saying "If fpath is null at this very moment in the execution of this script, then goto label 'ErrorHandler' otherwise continue on with the script"

Comment: Hi @LittleBobbyTables, thank you for taking the time for replying. It is very possible that these lines are incorrect. I must admit, this is somehting that is a little new to me, so I'm trying to work this out as I go along. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: I think you are getting this confused with a line like `On Error Goto ErrorHandler` which switches VBA's internal error handling to go to your label instead of just erroring out and ending the script. The difference is between `ON ERROR...` and `IF <condition>` The first changes how VBA executes, the second just tests for the `<condition>` at that line and continues on.

Comment: I agree with swapping the lines around. The other thing is, the if statement only checks if the filepath supplied is null or not. This is not the same as checking whether the folder exists or not. you can use something like `If Not Dir(fpath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then`

Comment: All, thank you for your comments. I've updated my code as shown in my original post. The problem I have that the rest of the code is still running because I see the iMessage shown at the end of my script and I now 'Resume Next' error? Kind regards

Comment: Try adding a label after your error handling code block like `SKIP_ERR_HANDLING:` then end the sub and just before the error handling block put a `Go To SKIP_ERR_HANDLING`. Right now your code runs into the error handling block even when there are no errors (after it has executed all of the previous code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, thank you for your help and guidance. I just wanted to let you know that with help from a work colleague, I've come up with the code as shown below. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim fPath As String

    On Error GoTo errHandler:
'Display the splash form non-modally.
    Set frm = New frmSplash
    With frm
        .TaskDone = False
        .prgStatus.Value = 0
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show False
    End With

    For j = 1 To 1000
        DoEvents
        Next j

        iRow = 17
        fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\"
        If Dir(fPath) = "" Then
            Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            If FSO.FolderExists(fPath) = False Then
'' Code will run here if folder does not exist
                GoTo errHandler
            Else
                Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)
                IsSubFolder = True
                Call DeleteRows
''''''''
'' Get the max number of files in all the folders and subfolders
''''''''
                xCur = 1 'set start value for xCur here as will reset when recurssively calling ListFilesInFolder
                xMax = SourceFolder.Files.Count
                For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
                    xMax = xMax + SubFolder.Files.Count
                    Next SubFolder
''
                    Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
''
                    Call FormatCells
                End If
            End If

            frm.TaskDone = True
            Unload frm
'The row below creates a 'On Screen' message telling the user that the workbook has been built.
            MsgBox "The list has now been been updated!"
            Exit Sub
''
errHandler:
            frm.TaskDone = True
            Unload frm
            MsgBox "The file path doesn't exist, please contact the administrator", , "File Path Error"
''
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle it like this

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\April 2015\"

    If Dir(fPath) <> "" Then
    End If

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        frm.prgStatus.Value = 15
        If FSO.........
```